# Map of string and vector Questions

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

Hello all i made simple program that takes name of the city and temperature and store the temperatures in vector which in the map and print the min and max temperature of the city .

i have two  questions :

1.In my code i'm creating vector out of the map and when fill it from the loop
but it is possible to make it like that:

```
Mymap[town].push_back(firstTemperatur);
Mymap[town].push_back(secondTemperatur);
```

2.i'm taking the min and max value of the vector but im using function min_element and max_element and tried to make it with my own algorithm but when i want to iterate it over the vector but when iterate  it over it the vector size is 0 and i can not understand why is empty when the vector in the map is not empty?

This is the code with custom algorithm

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include <climits>
int main ()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> Mymap;


    int numOfIterations;

    std::cin >> numOfIterations;

   auto it = Mymap.begin();

    std::string town;

    int firstTemperatur;

    int secondTemperatur;

    std::vector<int>  values;


    for (int i = 0; i < numOfIterations;)
    {
         bool keyFinded = false;
        std::cin >> town;
        std::cin >> firstTemperatur;
        std::cin >> secondTemperatur;
            for( it = Mymap.begin(); it != Mymap.end(); it++ )
            {
                if( it == Mymap.find( town ) )
                {
                    keyFinded = true;
                }
            }
            if(!keyFinded)
            {
                ++i;
            }
          values = Mymap[town];
          values.push_back(firstTemperatur);
          values.push_back(secondTemperatur);
    }
    for (it = Mymap.begin(); it != Mymap.end(); it++)
    {


             std::vector<int>::iterator big;
         int smallest_element = INT_MAX; 
        int largest_element = INT_MIN;

        for(; big != it->second.end(); ++big)  
        {
            if(it->second[*big] < smallest_element)
            {
            smallest_element = it->second[*big];
            }
            if(it->second[*big] > largest_element)
            {
                largest_element = it->second[*big];
            }
        }
        std::cout << it->first << " " << smallest_element  << " " <<  largest_element  <<  std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The vector size in the map is  " << it->second.size();
    }




            return 0;
}
```

that is the working  code (all it's working with it )

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
int main ()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> Mymap;


    int numOfIterations;

    std::cin >> numOfIterations;

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>::iterator it = Mymap.begin();

    std::string town;

    int firstTemperatur;

    int secondTemperatur;

    std::vector<int> values;


    for (int i = 0; i < numOfIterations;)
    {
         bool keyFinded = false;
        std::cin >> town;
        std::cin >> firstTemperatur;
        std::cin >> secondTemperatur;
         for( it = Mymap.begin(); it != Mymap.end(); it++ )
        {
            if( it == Mymap.find( town ) )
            {
                keyFinded = true;

            }

        }

        if(!keyFinded)
        {
            ++i;
        }

          std::vector<int>& values = Mymap[town];
          values.push_back(firstTemperatur);
          values.push_back(secondTemperatur);



    }

           for( it = Mymap.begin(); it != Mymap.end(); it++ )
            {
                auto minval = *std::min_element(it->second.begin(), it->second.end());
                auto maxval = *std::max_element(it->second.begin(), it->second.end());

                std::cout << it->first << " " << minval  << " " <<  maxval  <<  std::endl;
            }
        return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: In the non-working code, you haven't initialized `big`.

Comment: Concerning 1st question: why do you think it could not work. Why did not you try?

Comment: how to initialize it ? i made iterator of vector of int . it is not  this the right  initialization?

Comment: @Damien Hello i tried but it was not working  https://pastebin.com/Y4DUYDMN

Comment: Given how you are using it, `big = it->second.begin();` I guess.

Comment: If this programme (in the link) is not working, it is not because of these two lines

Comment: yes yes i made mistake sorry about it  i posed wrong code.  Why when i want to iterate over the vector of the map to take the min and max value  the size of it->second,size() is ?

Comment: @Damien it worked with your suggestion but why in my code does not getting the value of the biggest and the smallest i made debug  and does not assign the values i can not understand why does not assign ? https://pastebin.com/80AShXBb

Comment: in this last programme, `big` is an iterator on the vector of temperatures. Therefore, `it->second[*big]` shall be replaced by `*big`. Moreover, all the lines with `Keyfinded` seem useless (but do not harm). The modified code work for me (tested).

Comment: @Damien Thank you very much for the spent time and very useful answers . Wish you all the beset

Comment: Happy to have been able to help you